# PYMC3 Seasonal Variables

Tags: python, bayesian, pymc, pymc3

I'm relatively new to PYMC3 and I'm trying to implement a Bayesian Structure Time Series (BSTS) without regressors, for instance the model fit [here](http://multithreaded.stitchfix.com/blog/2016/04/21/forget-arima/) in R. The model is as follows:

[image: model]

I can implement the local linear trend using a GaussianRandomWalk as follows:

```
delta = pymc3.GaussianRandomWalk('delta',mu=0,sd=1,shape=99)
mu = pymc3.GaussianRandomWalk('mu',mu=delta,sd=1,shape=100)
```

However, I'm at a loss for how to encode the seasonal variable (tau) in PYMC3. Do I need to roll a custom random walk class or is there some other trick?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
w = pm.Normal('w', sd=sigma_tau, shape=S)
tau = w - tt.concatenate([[0.], w.cumsum()[:-1]])
```

Depending on the data it might also be faster to use `cumsum` for the other random walks, that often avoids correlations in the posterior, which makes life easier for the sampler.

Comment: Its not really clear to me why this would give the correct form of tau, can you elaborate? At any rate, this produces a dimension mismatch. If I take S = 12, then tau is a 12-dimensional vector whereas mu is a 100-dimensional. This prevents me from forming y=pm.Normal('y',mu=mu+tau,sd=sigma_y,observed=y_train). Also, I guess when you say cumsum trick for the walks you mean u=pm.Normal('u',sd=sigma_delta) and delta=u+tt.concatenate([[0.],u.cumsum()[:-1]])?

Comment: I would like to accept your response so that you can get your reputation, but I cannot without clairification regarding tensor shapes and forming y (see previous comment).